# how to cut a portion of a variable and put it into another

Tags: php, string

I have 2 variables that are defined as follow,

```
$a = abc.php? b=1a1a;
$b = abc.php? b=0;
```

How can I replace `'1a1a'` of variable `$a` into `0` of variable `$b`.

That means variable `b` will be `$b = abc.php ? b=1a1a;`

And, could anyone please tell me if `$a = abc.php? b=1a1a;` then how can I get `$c = 1a1a`, that means anything after `'b='`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$a='abc.php?b=1a1a';
$b='abc.php?b=0';
$newstr=substr($a,strpos($a,'=')+1);
$replacestr=substr($b,strpos($b,'=')+1);
$pattern='/('.$replacestr.')/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $newstr, $b);
```

**Note:-** THis will replace everything after **=** in your `$b` with everything after **=** in your `$a`

**Update 2**
If I understood your second question properly then i think you want this

```
$a='abc.php?a=2a2&b=1a1a' ;
$b='abc.php?a=2a2&b=0';
$newstr=substr($a,strripos($a,'=')+1);
$replacestr=substr($b,strripos($b,'=')+1);
$pattern='/('.$replacestr.')/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $newstr, $b);
```

Here it will replace everything after the **LAST =** it finds in string **$b** with everything after the **LAST =** it finds in string **$a**

Comment: if $a='abc.php?a=2a2&b=1a1a' ;
$b='abc.php?a=2a2&b=0';
then how could I do it ?